# Connect Ask Ubuntu with Help

Tags: feature-request

I will be more easy for the user to ask any thing from there Ubuntu.

The idea to add Ask Ubuntu inside the menu of help. that will help Ubuntu user to ask about specifies thing related the application. for example, if I want to ask about Mplayer all what I need is to open Mplayer from the menu Help> Ask Ubuntu, which will show to the user all the questions that is related to the application system and so on.

that will make asking question better because some of the important tags is collected from the user automatically such as (32-bit or 64-bit)  (Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10) (name of the application). that will lead to increase quality of the questions.

As I believe it will be hard to add this feature in each application. for that, it can also added a `Ask Ubuntu` button beside  `more info` button in Ubuntu software center for each application there

Answer (score 4):

There's currrently a *Help->Get Help Online...* option in most/all Ubuntu programs.

[image: Screenshot]

It would be very cool if that could be linked up to Ask Ubuntu rather than [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/).

That could be changed in each application individually. But perhaps at some point in the future Launchpad Answers might be discontinued and all the links within programs could be automatically redirected here.

Comment: Maybe we should file a bug on LP to get a link added.